# i can't get dropdown list to configure subscriptions and rendering formats while using roports on report manager in ssrs in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

i can't get dropdown list to configure subscriptions and rendering formats while using roports on report manager in ssrs in sql server 2008 r2.I tried it on several browsers IE, Mozilla and chrome but no use. while put the cursor on specific report it shows "items in home" instead of drop down list.

could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, after much searching around the web the solution appears to be viewing the page in **IE using compatibility mode**... hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several differences in the way that older versions of IE handle javascript compared with modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.

The easiest way that I have found to fix SSRS 2008 R2 is to set IE to use compatibility mode for my SSRS site and only use IE to manage SSRS.

However, I was unable to convince all my users that they should switch to IE, so I had to find a more universal solution.  To get SSRS 2008 R2 to work in modern browsers I modified the ReportingServices.js file found in the folder **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js**.

I fixed the following issues:

- element.value has been replaced with element.getAttribute("value")
- table.cells.length has been replaced with table.rows.length
- table.cells[index] has been replaced with table.rows[index].cells[0]
- A basic “GetElementsByClass” function was added to get around differences in the way “lastChild” works
- A “pageLoad” function was added that updates the element.style.overflow value of the div that holds rendered reports

You can make these modifications yourself, but for convenience you can view the entire ReportingServices.js file that I am using at [www.pottersolutions.com/ssrs-2008-r2.html](http://www.pottersolutions.com/ssrs-2008-r2.html) (the file is too big to post in this reponse).

Always remember to make a backup of your file before making any modifications!